# Communicating with web service on SSL

Tags: web-services, web-applications, ssl, wsimport

I have a web service which previously was deployed on http. I used to generate stub classes using wsimport using wsimport http://localhost:8080/MiniForumService/MiniForumService?wsdl.

Now I deployed it on SSL. But when I try to generate the stub classes from it using wsimport https://localhost:8443/MiniForumService/MiniForumService?wsdl but I'm getting the following error:

```
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm using a self-signed certificate on the server. How can I solve this please? I've googled about but haven't found a solution till now

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Netbeans and Metro, this [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/wsit.html) may help you.

This trick is to check the "Secure Service" check-box as described.